# Sortable react material UI table with specific to date column

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a react material UI table that displays some data. I want to be able to sort the table according to latest date records to the first , Is there a way to do so by default?

```
<TableHead style={{ backgroundColor: "lightgrey" }}>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Location</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Slot-Time </TableCell>

                <TableCell align="right" ><TableSortLabel onClick={() => handleSort('fromDate')}>From Date</TableSortLabel></TableCell>

                <TableCell align="right">From Time</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">To Date</TableCell> 
                <TableCell align="right">To Time</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Days in Week</TableCell>
                <TableCell> </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {resultTable &&
                resultTable.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).sort(order === 'asc'? ascCompare: desCompare ).map((n) => {
                  return (
                    <TableRow key={n.id}>
                      <TableCell>
                       { facilitiesList ? getFacilityName(n.facilityId) : ""} 
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.slotTime}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{Moment(n.fromDate, "DD-MM-YYYY").format("MMMM Do YYYY")} </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.fromTime}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{Moment(n.toDate, "DD-MM-YYYY").format("MMMM Do YYYY")}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.toTime}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">
                        {n.daysOfWeek
                          .split(",")
                          .map((day) => {
                            return days[parseInt(day) - 1];
                          })
                          .join()}
                      </TableCell>`
```

Comment: Why don't you sort data on the server before sending it to clientside?

Comment: i think that will be a good option rather than sorting data on client side . thanks @Michael for suggesting

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please upvote my answer below. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.date is less than b.date) { // u can convert date into second to compare
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.date is greater than b.date ) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a.date must be equal to b.date
  return 0;
}
```

and fix :

```js
...resultTable.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).sort(compare).map...
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can sort a particular column using the compare function.** Generally, we sort array according to date is like this `new Date(b) - new Date(a)`. Add valueOf() to avoid the TS Error.

```js
function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
  if (orderBy === 'date') {
    return (new Date(b[orderBy]).valueOf() - new Date(a[orderBy]).valueOf());
  }
  if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) return -1;
  if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should sort the data on the server before sending it to clientside